# Can we change rabbitmq properties spring config and stream rabbit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-config

In my POC, I am using Spring Cloud Config and Spring Stream Rabbit. I want to dynamically change number of listeners (concurrency). Is it possible to do that? I want to do following:

1) If there are too many messages in queue, i want to increase concurrency level.

2) In scenario where my downstream system is not available, I want to stop processing messages from queue (in short concurrency level 0).

How i can achieve this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener container running in the binder supports such changes (although you can't go down to 0, but the container can be `stop()` ped).

However, spring-cloud-stream provides no mechanism for you to get a reference to the listener container.

You might want to consider using a `@RabbitListener` from [Spring AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven) instead - it will give you complete control over the listener container.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Let me try that approach.